# Set Command, which is defined in other assembly, in xaml cause the application crash

Tags: wpf

I have create a solution which contains two project:

project 1. used for define some common classes, such as:

```
    public class ApplicationCommands
    {
        private static DelegateCommand _edit;

        public static DelegateCommand Edit
        {
            get
            {
                if (_edit== null)
                    _edit= new DelegateCommand(EditExecute, EditCanExecute);

                return _edit;
            }
        }
    }
```

project 2. will use the command defined in the common class assembly in XAML is like:

```
    <Window x:Class="Edit.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:edit="clr-namespace:Edit;assembly=Edit"
            Title="MainWindow"
            Height="600"
            Width="700">
        <Grid>
            <Button Command="edit:ApplicationCommands.Edit"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

When I run the application the exception was thrown at line:

```
    <Button Command="edit:ApplicationCommands.Edit"/>
```

and the exception message is "{"Type reference cannot find type named '{clr-namespace:Edit;assembly=Edit}ApplicationCommands'."}". But when I open the dll, the ApplicationCommands is in the dll.

When I move the ApplicationCommands class to the project 2 and the used it it works perfectly.

Can anyone tell me, do I miss anything for exposing the class or static members from one assembly to others, or consuming the class or static members exposed by other assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `Binding`'s in the `Command`

```
<Button Command="{Binding Source="{x:Static edit:ApplicationCommands.Edit}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this race condition, assign the edit command to a stack variable after the initialization of the page and see if the same happens. Something about loading a DLL from xaml *appears* to be in a race condition. If it still occurs, assign it to a property on the page or VM and bind to it from the xaml.